# Component of the real line

Tags: general-topology

What is the maximal connected subset of the real line.
I know that connected subsets of real line are empty set, whole space and intervals (Singleton sets also).
But since every component of space is closed, so the maximal connected subset is whole space itself?

Can anyone clear my doubt.
Thanks in advance

Comment: A maximal component in a connected space is, well, the space itself. You can't go bigger than that.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed the whole space $\mathbb{R}$, which is itself connected and clearly maximal.